# Trouble accessing a long-forgotton Facebook Photo Album

Tags: facebook, facebook-photos

I have a couple of Facebook photo albums saved on my bookmarks, from many years ago.

I'd like to access the photos within, but I have several problems:

1. I don't know which person the album belongs to.
2. I very much doubt that person is still on my friends list.
3. I don't know what I'm doing

Could anyone help?

The bookmarked links are:

https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=a.1465881945045.43888.1773447629&type=1

https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=a.1945722211783.118409.1504351966&type=1

Comment: If you're no longer friends with the person who owns the album, don't know who it was, and you're not tagged in any of the photos, I'm afraid you're out of luck.

Comment: I think I know who owns the album, and I think I'm still friends with them. But I think she might have deleted the album, as it still says 'This content is currently unavailable'

Answer (score 2):

The breakdown on the numeric parameter is something like

1. Facebook object id of the photo
2. Type of photo (Album, Profile picture, App)
3. Facebook profile id

You want 3. So if you are still friends with these people

- facebook.com/1773447629
- facebook.com/1504351966

Then you can ask them about the pictures.